# Hot Peppers in Olive Oil Safe?

Tags: food-safety

I chopped up some raw assorted hot peppers, covered them with olive oil and then refrigerated them immediately. How long will they keep in the fridge?

Comment: also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/botulism-garlic-cold-pressed-olive-oil-and-mason-jars?rq=1, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/how-can-i-infuse-olive-oil-safely?rq=1, and, for encompassing info on food safety, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer. Your infused oil falls into the "cooked dishes" part, because there is nothing in there to prevent bacteria growth - so the general rule of "3-4 days in the fridge" applies to it too.

Answer (score 0):

Anything stored in olive oil is subject to bacterial growth, even in the fridge. If it is in an air tight container, such as a mason jar, it should last about 1 week. :)